# How to integrate a SteveMorse.org PHP database on a Wordpress Theme page

Tags: php, custom-wordpress-pages

I created a PHP engine database using the SteveMorse.org 'One-Step' database system. https://stevemorse.org/create/faq.htm
   The database works fine on my non-wordpress domain: 
http://ronaldimiller.com/companyL/index2.html
 Now I have a Wordpress site and would like to migrate the database.

I created a child theme, created a template for php. The database search form is on a Wordpress page and when run, generates a 'Can't read database' which is a text file (Tab delimited).  This indicates to me that the form reads the engine.php file but can't read the database and thus can't display the data output.  I'm self-taught and don't know much php but can follow directions. My guess is that all I need is the correct coding on my functions.php file, and/or some other file.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I know an alternative would be to use mySQL but I've never used it and hope I can migrate the database that I created and works.  Sorry for the long post.  TIA, Ron

Comment: Found the solution . . . . easy peasy.  Create a Wordpress sub-domain; add the sub-domain folder in Public_html and add the files.  Link from Wordpress page to the index.html search form.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution . . . . easy peasy.  Create a Wordpress sub-domain; add the sub-domain folder in Public_html and add the files.  Link from Wordpress page to the index.html search form.